# Не работает нейронка C#

Tags: c#, .net

Я делал нейронку по распознаванию картинок с рукописными цифрами 28х28 пикселей на C#. В функцию, которая засовывает значения массива во входные нейроны и потом все считает (TestNeuralNetwork), передается информация о яркости каждого пикселя на картинке от 0 до 1. Вот примеры картинок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Картинки по-быстрому для теста нарисованы в пеинте.*

Значения из массива о яркости задаются в значения каждому входному нейрону, и потом все умножается на веса и т.п.. Вот код как все делается:

```
private void RecalculateResult()
    {
        // ziro layer with first input neurons - перемножается нулевой слой скрытых нейронов на входные.
        for (int hidden = 0; hidden < HiddenNeurons[0].Length; hidden++)
        {
            HiddenNeurons[0][hidden].value = 0;
            for (int input = 0; input < InputNeurons.Length; input++)
            {
                HiddenNeurons[0][hidden].value += HiddenNeurons[0][hidden].weights[input] * InputNeurons[input].value;
            }
        }
        // remaining layers of hidden neurons - перемножается от первого слоя до последнего
        for (int layer = 1; layer < HiddenNeurons.Length; layer++)
        {
            for (int hidden = 0; hidden < HiddenNeurons[layer].Length; hidden++)
            {
                HiddenNeurons[layer][hidden].value = 0;
                for (int prevHidden = 0; prevHidden < HiddenNeurons[layer-1].Length; prevHidden++)
                {
                    HiddenNeurons[layer][hidden].value += HiddenNeurons[layer][hidden].weights[prevHidden] * HiddenNeurons[layer-1][prevHidden].value;
                }
            }
        }
        // output neurons calculate - перемножаются веса выходных с последними скрытыми.
        for (int output = 0; output < OutputNeurons.Length; output++)
        {
            OutputNeurons[output].value = 0;
            for (int lastHidden = 0; lastHidden < HiddenNeurons[HiddenNeurons.Length-1].Length; lastHidden++)
            {
                OutputNeurons[output].value += OutputNeurons[output].weights[lastHidden] * HiddenNeurons[HiddenNeurons.Length-1][lastHidden].value;
            }
        }
    }
```

InputNeurons, HiddenNeurons и OutputNeurons - это все массивы которые содержат в себе экземпляры классов:

```
public class InputNeuron
{
    public double value;
    public InputNeuron(double value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
public class HiddenNeuron
{
    public double value;
    public double[] weights;
    public HiddenNeuron(double[] weights)
    {
        this.weights = weights;
    }
}
public class OutputNeuron
{
    public double value;
    public double[] weights;
    public string association;
    public OutputNeuron(double[] weights, string association)
    {
        this.weights = weights;
        this.association = association;
    }
}
```

HiddenNeurons - многомерный массив т.к. может быть несколько скрытых слоёв.

Входные нейроны задаются правильно, я это проверил в дебаге. Но, где здесь ошибка при которой постоянно на выходе побеждает один и тот же выходной нейрон?

Кому нужно, вот целый проект решения Visual Studio на гитхабе:[GitHub](https://github.com/DaniilSkLi/NeuralNetwork_0.1)

Comment: `pixel.R + pixel.B + pixel.B` => `pixel.R + pixel.G + pixel.B`. Но есть еще метод `Color.GetBrightness()`. А по поводу самого вопроса, низвестно, почему у вас массив не меняется, что-то не так за пределами показанного кода.

Comment: @aepot Вы правы, почему-то когда было два раза Blue массив не менялся через дебаг, хз почему. Но теперь другая проблема, на выходе из нейронки выходит одно и то же число - побеждает один и тот же выходной нейрон, при чем всегда, сколько бы я раз не перезапускал программу (обновляются веса на новый рандом).

Comment: Машинное обучение - сложная и узкая тема. Врядли вы быстро сможете получить здесь ответ.